# sha256 doesn't match across environments in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am stuck at a weird problem. I am trying to make sure that 2 different environments (like Dev and Test) have the same image of my app, by looking at the sha256 using the following command

```
kubectl describe pod abc-auth-99f5f4565-g25bn
...
  abc-auth:
    Container ID:   docker://0baa598d2f52ae83a3b4af8325be59ca0f046463c21d3ef53e136a490eeec294
    Image:          abc-seal-tools:5000/abc-auth:valid-f-test
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://abc-seal-tools:5000/abc-auth@sha256:6a0918c36a084b454910b3bdd077d64640d8be8ab939b58ee0733651c8c69723
```

On one env I see sha256:6a0918c36a084b454910b3bdd077d64640d8be8ab939b58ee0733651c8c69723, but on another env I see a different sha256 one.

I am tagging the image as following in lower env as shown below

```
docker pull abc-seal-tools:5000/abc-auth:valid-f-test
docker tag abc-seal-tools:5000/abc-auth:valid-f-test abc-seal-tools:5000/abc-auth:valid-fe2ef-test
docker push abc-seal-tools:5000/abc-auth:valid-fe2ef-test
...
valid-fe2ef-test: digest: sha256:6a0918c36a084b454910b3bdd077d64640d8be8ab939b58ee0733651c8c69723 size: 2423
```

in the higher env, I am do the deployment of this app using

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: abc-auth
    image: abc-seal-tools:5000/abc-auth:valid-fe2ef-test
    imagePullPolicy: Always
```

after deployment is successfull, I am doing a kubectl describe pod abc-auth and seeing a different sha256 for some reason.

```
Image ID:       docker-pullable://abc-seal-tools:5000/abc-auth@sha256:35ce6e5254eaf5b9d3c77d2606d99b5827aa9d694b7353448c9cacd3ba059b08
```

I don't get why the sha256 is not matching even though I am pulling the correct tag, any ideas will be appreciated gratefully

Comment: I presume you've tried replacing the `:valid-fe2ef-test` with `@sha256:35ce6...` to force the images to be _exactly_ the same, or cause `docker pull` to otherwise bail out? I hear you about the tag, and `imagePullPolicy: Always` but **declaring** a `@sha256:` should be a cheap experiment but may be highly enlightening

Comment: You may also be interested in manually investigating the docker-registry metadata: `curl -k -v -H 'Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json' https://abc-seal-tools:5000/v2/abc-auth/tags/list | jq .` and see if you spot anything weird

Comment: @sbolla what docker registry do you use? And what docker and kubernetes versions do you have?

Comment: so basically, it looks like the RepoDigests are the ones I should be looking at. Because if I do a docker inspect --format='{{.RepoDigests}}' $IMAGE I get the RepoDigests of that image. But, when I do a kubectl describe <POD_NAME> it doesn't show all the RepoDigests. It only shows the latest one. How can I get all the RepoDigests using kubectl describe <POD-NAME> or some other command

Comment: @sbolla sorry for answering to long. `docker inspect` RepoDigests corresponds to `kubectl discribe` Image ID field